# How to limit connection per ip using Nginx on windows

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2008, limit

My website is underattack, i have to limit connection per ip but i can't, i read the nginx documentation and when i add the ..

```
 limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
server {

    location /download/ {
        limit_conn addr 1;
    }
```

to my `nginx.conf` (I'm using WT-NMP portable nginx, php, mysql windows appl.), nginx is not working. I can use e.g `limit_rate 700k` in server section but i can not use `limit_conn_zone` in http section. I dont understand why i can not use these codes. hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

I can use this code to limit bandwith eg..

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
      mp4;
        limit_rate 700k;
    }
```

Comment: Describe "not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original nginx for Windows is severely limited, what you want to use, uses shared memory which does not work as well as other things, there is a re-developed version where shared memory works and allows limit_conn to work as well, see: http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which nginx should i download in this link ? And maybe it will be stupid question, is it possible to change nginx version in WTNMP ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do, nginx_basic is a full replacement for nginx's version, see also #14 in the FAQ. Yes you can replace any nginx version with this version.

Comment: Thank you again. I cant understand which nginx is supporting `limit_conn_zone` etc.. in http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/ . There are lots of downloads **Cheshire**, **Snowman**, **Alice**, **Butterfly**, **Caterpillar** etc.. . I just want to find right nginx version and limit my connection with new nginx using WTNMP.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the one from the frontpage, thats always the latest release, just like any other software there are older versions on record in the download folder, but if you stick with what the frontpage says you'll be ok.

Comment: Thank you.. then i will try **nginx 1.7.4.1 RedKnight.zip** Hope it helps.